# Repeat command in while loop or similar until not existing result is found

Tags: python, django, loops, while-loop, subprocess

i need to repeat a cmd which always generated a new random string, after that i need to make sure that this specific string has not been generated before. I never did while loops before and im not able to figure out how to repate the cmd until a result has been found which is not already part of the database. I can't be to specific as this source is closed

all this is packed into a celery task

tasks.py

```
@app.task
def allocate_new_string(user_pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
    new_string = subprocess.Popen("$get_new_string_cmd", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[
        0].decode('utf-8').strip()
    try:
        while True:
            if Used_String.objects.filter(string=new_string, atom=0).exists():
                new_string << how to repeat the command from above here until a new random string has been found?
            else:
                used_string = Used_String.objects.create(user=user, string=new_string, atom=0)
                used_string.save()
                logger.info(str("New String has been set)
    except:
        logger.info(str("Something went wrong while processing the task"))
```

The function i want to have here is: Search for a none existing sting  until one has found that has never been generated before or is at least not part of the database.
the cmd im using isn't openSSL or something like that and it's quite likly that i hit two times the same random generated string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use a UUID field which is as close to guaranteed to be unique as you'll need

Comment: Impossible at this point as the sequence my new_string is generated from follows a mathematical principle which has to be used at this point. We already watched for several ways around this but at this point this is sadly the only option. Thanks your interest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight change.

```py
@app.task
def allocate_new_string(user_pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
    try:
        Found = True
        while Found:
            new_string = subprocess.Popen("$get_new_string_cmd", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[
        0].decode('utf-8').strip()
            if Used_String.objects.filter(string=new_string, atom=0).exists():
                Found = True
            else:
                used_string = Used_String.objects.create(user=user, string=new_string, atom=0)
                used_string.save()
                logger.info(str("New String has been set"))
                Found = False
    except:
        logger.info(str("Something went wrong while processing the task"))
```

I have not tested it but should work. Please try it out and let me know.

Comment: Well this seems to work exactly the way i wanted to be, thanks for you corrections on my code, I really appreciate that.